# How to get a variable from a php file and use it in a Android activity?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-activity

I have created a app that uses a mysql database which is on web server. I'm inserting some records using a php file, like this:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
        require 'connection.php';
        createUsername();
    }

    function createUsername() {

        global $connect;

        $username = $_POST["username"]; 

        $query = " INSERT INTO statistics(username) VALUES ('$username');";

        $result = $connect->query($query);
        $lastInsertId = $connect->insert_id;

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($lastInsertId);
    }
?>
```

I need to use the `$lastInsertId` variable in my Android activity. I try to do this using `VOLLEY. This my code:

```
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequestLastInsertId = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            try {
                JSONArray ids = response.getJSONArray("lastInsertId");
                for (int i = 0; i < ids.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject student = ids.getJSONObject(i);

                    String lastInsertId = student.getString(this);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lastInsertId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.append(error.getMessage());

        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequestLastInsertId);
```

Were am i wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What getting in `System.out.println(response.toString());` line in log?

Comment: In the line log `println` returns the id. But why the `Toast` is not working? Do you think i need to convert the `JSONObject` to string?

Comment: Show String which getting from `System.out.println(response.toString());`

Comment: This is what i'm getting: `I/System.out: 111`. Is the exact id that id need.

Comment: `111 ` is not valid json string, so no need to convert String to JSONObject just use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I deleted all the unnecessary lines but the `Toast` doesn't work. My code looks like [that](http://gogo.ro/32.txt) What do you think is missing?

Comment: try to use `String.ValueOf(response.toString())` and instead of `getApplicationContext()` use current Activity Context using `CurrentActivityName.this`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95960/discussion-between-alex-m-and--k).

Comment: If i use `String.ValueOf(response.toString())` i get this error: `I/System.out: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject121`. What can be done? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending only a number back as a response. I would send something more JSON-ish, like this:

```
echo json_encode(array("lastInsertId" => $lastInsertId));
```

You assume that there is a json array called `lastInsertId` in your response:

```
JSONArray ids = response.getJSONArray("lastInsertId");
```

The code above is incorrect. `lastInsertId` is a key in your Android code which opens a numeric value. If you still have trouble, then please, leave a comment here with further details.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yes, `lastInsertId` is a key in my Android code which opens a numeric value but i cannot use it. I still have problem. I  simplified the code and looks like [this](http://gogo.ro/32.txt) So, with this code, the system `System.out.println` the id perfectly but when i try to convert the int to string, the `Toast` doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: I also tried to use: `String.valueOf(response);` but `Toast` contains a `null` value.

Comment: @AlexM., you can get a value from a JSONObject using a key, for example look here: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Getting a value from a JSONObject using a key solved my problem. Thank you!